# Why i am not able to see the records of file that i uploaded in storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azureportal

I have azure free trail account , I want to create a new storage account and then i want to upload a file to a container in it and then i want to view the records of that file i upload

1. Create a resource group
2. created a storage account and added that to resoure group
3. Clicked upload and uploaded a file from my laptop , I see that file is uploaded , but not able to see the records .

Please help how do i see the records of the file that i uploaded

[image]

Comment: what do you mean with *I see that file is uploaded , but not able to see the records .*. Did you expect to see a preview with the file content?

Comment: Yes, I want to see the preview of file

Comment: Ok, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot view the blob content from within the "Manage uploads" page. Please browse to the container and then use the context menu like demonstrated in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Great, I got it now , Thanks for your help